# How do I select only one row when there are multiple rows with the same business meaning?

Tags: sql

My table looks something like below:

```
From    To     Distance
-----------------------
ATL     NY     100
NY      ATL    100
DAL     NY     300
NY      DAL    300
DAL     MCI    200
MCI     DAL    200
```

In this case the first two rows have the same business meaning and likewise the third and fourth (its basically the same routes but the from to varies based on the trip).

I need the output to be like

```
ATL   NY    100
DAL   NY    100
DAL   MCI   200
```

The idea is I need only identical rows that has different business meaning. So I want either first or second row and third or fourth row.

Thanks in advance for the help :)

Comment: please tag the dbms you are using.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE To = 'NY'`

Comment: When you added the SQL tag, a big box appeared on the screen suggesting you also add a tag for the specific DBMS you're using. Is there a reason you decided to just ignore it? It suggested that for a reason; there are syntax and functionality differences between them, so knowing which specific one you're using is important. If you want help, provide the details needed, **especially** when the site shows a great big box suggesting you do so and telling you **exactly** how to do so.

Comment: @KenWhite, there's also a SQL standard.  The OP's question is trivial, relates to how to use SQL.  He evidently hasn't gotten to the chapter in his textbook that describes `distinct`.  Some questions are product-specific; this one is not.

Comment: I just want the logic to be implemented irrespective to the DBMS

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple

`SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE To = 'NY'`

Answer (score 0):

Two Possibilities, as you want only distinct records

```
Select From,To,Distance from table_name
Group By From,To,Distance
```

OR

```
Select Distinct From,To,Distance from table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select DISTINCT "From", To, Distance from T
```

I don't know whether to answer your question or provide a query that produces the result you want, and I don't know what *one row that will have same routes* means.  The above query answers the question phrased in your title, not the output you described.

I put `"From"` in quotes for a reason.  *From* is an SQL keyword.  In SQL, column names are known as *identifiers*.  There's no rule prohibiting an identifier from looking like a keyword, but it can be confusing to humans and is sometimes confusing to the SQL parser.  To distinguish, the rule in SQL is that any string in double-quotes is treated as an identifier.

If I have a choice, I avoid using identifiers that are also keywords.  There are lots of from-to things in databases; most of them are just as clear when named *start-until* or similar.  Yours might be *origin-destination*.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM table_name GROUP BY From HAVING COUNT(From) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Responding to a very old thread, but I hope the solution will help someone looking in similar lines. I think the OP is looking for a query to return One row per distance.

```
WITH added_rownum AS
(
 SELECT    *,    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Distance ORDER BY 
   "From") AS rn  FROM table_name
)
SELECT "From", "To", "Distance" FROM added_rownum ar WHERE ar.rn=1;
```